# Is it possible to have LDAPS with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ldap

I have my nodejs application up and run with LDAP (Window Server 2012 R2). It is working fine as expected. The only issue that I encounter is, it's sending plain username and password, is it possible to implement LDAPS instead of LDAP?

Comment: ldapjs supports ldaps  http://ldapjs.org/client.html

Comment: @Roshith, Thank a lot...